# svchost.exe system error on login

Tags: windows-10, svchost

I have a fresh installed Windows 10--wiped everything before installing it. Now, for the first time ever, when I log in I get the follow message

> The system detected an overrun of a stack=based buffer in this application. This overrun could potentially allow a malicious user to gain control of this application.

Do I have a memory leak somewhere somehow? What could be the cause when Windows is fresh installed? Ideas on how to fix it?

I search a bit online, and have tried the following with no success

```
sfc /scannow
DISM /online /cleanup-image/ restorehealth
```

The last post I checked suggested doing a `Windows Repair Upgrade` using the `Technical Preview` tool. I would like to avoid doing that if possible. Lastly, I have checked all `svchost.exe` services in `Task Manager` and confirm that they are all in my `C:\Windows\SYSTEM32` so no virus here.

Comment: Have you checked autoruns to see if there is a rogue svchost executable?

Comment: No, that's beyond my skill level! How do I do that?

Comment: Download autoruns from live.sysinternals.com and run it. Use the options to hide Microsoft entries and the search for svchost.

Comment: How do I tell if there is a rouge svchost executable? Am I looking for something specific?

Comment: Ram failure can throw this error, test your ram either from the bios or use this bootable program...https://www.memtest.org/

Comment: @Ptheguy when you `hide Microsoft entries` (`Options`, `Hide Microsoft entries`) you just need to type `svchost` into the Filter box and if it shows you anything at all, then it's a rogue (likely fake) svchost. This is used by some malware to conceal itself using a common name.

Comment: I get nothing when I hide `microsoft entries` and type `svchost`.